# When I try to send an api request to store details, image data in being sent as an object instead of being sent as form data. How can I fix this?

Tags: react-native

When I try to send an api request to store details, image data in being sent as an object instead of being sent as form data. I am working on react native.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You did not succeed in the api request.

Comment: i could'n send image binary

Answer (score 0):

```
* This is my solution. Its work for me *
 const uploadeImages = () => {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('image', {
                uri: PhotoRef.current['assets'][0].uri,
                name: ImageNameRef.current,
                path: PhotoRef.current['assets'][0].uri,
                newName: '123456',
                type: PhotoRef.current['assets'][0].type
            });
    
            let res = fetch('your link', { // Your POST endpoint
                method: 'POST',
                body: data, // This is your file object
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',
                },
            }).then((response) => {
                //   console.log('response'+response.text())  
                return response.json()
            })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.response == 1) {
    
                        console.log('setIsImage  true')
                        uploadeVideo2()
    
                    }
                })
        }
```